# OpenGL not rendering in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, opengl, mesa

I was practicing OpenGL by making small [demos](https://github.com/hellozee/gl-practice), the demos were running well but after I switched to Ubuntu 18.04, the objects are not rendering any more. The program compiles with no errors but I get blank screen with the background cleared with the desired color.

What is the probable problem?

I am using SDL2, SOIL, GLEW and glm too.

Here are the details regarding my card and driver:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: What's your graphics card? AMD, NVIDIA, Intel or something else?

Comment: Intel HD 620 to be specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue as this one: [Ubuntu 18.04 openGL/GLSL problem no textures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052588/ubuntu-18-04-opengl-glsl-problem-no-textures)

Basically, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ships with a new version of GLM.
The new version of GLM has changed the default constructor for matrices.

e.g.

```
model = glm::mat4();
```

must be changed to:

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

for the same behavior as earlier version of GLM.